# how to list installed packages from some command

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm working with ROS.

ROS provides some tools to install itself: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source

For example, to install the dependencies of ROS, we can execute `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y`.

Now I want to know which packages it installed exactly. I knew that we could list all of installed packages here: `/var/cache/apt/archives` but it contains all of packages. Is it possible to list the packages coming from one specific command (such as `rosdep install`)?

Comment: You can also check your apt history at /var/log/apt/history.log to see exactly what was installed. This question seems more ROS-related than Ubuntu-related.

Comment: `$ ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep list > installed-packages.txt`